# Use table column in hive window range

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to collect_list over a window, and i want to limit the window size dynamically based on the one column value from same table.

```
select concat_ws('->', collect_list(CASE WHEN b.colA IN ("bla", "blabla") THEN concat_ws("-", colB,colC) END) OVER (PARTITION BY colD ORDER BY time-stamp ROWS BETWEEN colE PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS myCol from ( select colA,colB,colC,colD,colE from mytable) a

colA|colB|colC|colD|colE|time-stamp
bla|abc|pqr|INDIA|1|2017-12-10
bla|abc|pqr|CHINA|1|2017-12-11
bla|abc|pqr|INDIA|2|2017-12-12
bla|abc|pqr|INDIA|3|2017-12-13
bla|abc|pqr|CHINA|2|2017-12-14
```

here hive doesnt accept colE in the range which has valid numaric values. i get error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 177:89 cannot recognize input near 'colE' 'preceding' 'AND' in windowframeboundary
```

Comment: can you add the full query you are trying?

Comment: added query and sample data

Comment: Hi，have you found a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics). Hive does not expetect any columns after the between word. The following are the available options

```
(ROWS | RANGE) BETWEEN (UNBOUNDED | [num]) PRECEDING AND ([num] PRECEDING | CURRENT ROW | (UNBOUNDED | [num]) FOLLOWING)
(ROWS | RANGE) BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND (CURRENT ROW | (UNBOUNDED | [num]) FOLLOWING)
(ROWS | RANGE) BETWEEN [num] FOLLOWING AND (UNBOUNDED | [num]) FOLLOWING
```